# How could Kiri control fish and plants in Avatar: The Way of Water?

Tags: character, avatar-the-way-of-water

[image: Kiri]

She seems to have a way to interact with the world that others do not possess. She demonstrated this power in the movie in at least three ways:

- Using glowing fish as a flash light while seeking her mother.
- Controlled the large anemone to attack the submersibles.
- Fish seemed to swarmed only her feet at the pier.

Especially during the anemone attack, the water tribe boys seemed to be amazed by the feat.

*Did I just miss the reference to how she has this power?*

Comment: ...Waterbending?

Comment: @TimPederick you got confused, this question is about the movie that was recently published, not about anime, comics, or some computer game. (I've seen results from all of those for that word you use, none is relevant)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Ah, I’m afraid it was actually a fourth category, humour—or my poor attempt at it, anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, it will be spelled out in the next films.

For now all we know is that her father is a mystery, and, apparently, she has inherited her special powers from him.

My theory is that her "father" is Eywa herself (despite being referred to as female, as a goddess she would have the power to father). Grace's body was too weak to sustain the personality/consciousness transfer attempted at the end of *Avatar 1*, but her avatar was capable of conceiving and bearing a child — in vegetative state on life support. So, in appreciation of how Grace respected and cared for the wellbeing of Pandora's nature, Eywa would have granted her this gift of pregnancy with a child who will now have those special powers.

Comment: I agree with your theory, and I go one step ahead: it doesn't matter who Kiri's father is but, in fact, what matters is who Kiri is, and I believe that she's Grace's "reincarnation". Just like Jake "moved" from his human body to his avatar body, Eywa actually "moved" Grace as well but as a new coming baby on her avatar body. That explains a lot two points: Kiri's deep bond with nature and Sigourney Weaver playing Kiri's role. It's very common in reincarnationist religions the fact that we don't remember who we were but we still carry some characterists and behaviours.